# Swift3 setting constraints relative to parent view of parent view

Tags: swift, swift3, autolayout, constraints

I have 3 classes, one is a a normal UIViewController in in which I have this code:

```
let CC0 = CustomUIView0()
self.addSubview(CC0)
```

the CustomUIView00 is a UIView class containing this code:

```
let CC1 = CustomUIView1()
self.addSubview(CC1)
```

Now for CC1 I would like to activate a constraint like this

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        NSLayoutConstraint(item: CC1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: ("Parent view of CC0"), attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

])
```

What I tried to do is to use the UIScreen.main in the toItem place but this throws an error saying that the item needs to be an instance of UIView for this to work.

So I would essentially like to create a constraint relative to the parent of the paren view, how could I do this.

***Update:***

UIViewController:

```
let CC0 = UICustomUIView0()
self.view.insertSubview(self.CC0, at: 0)
```

UICustomUIView0:

```
init {

super.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds);

let CC1 = UICustomUIView1()

guard let CC1Parent = self.CC1.superview, let CC0Parent = CC1Parent.superview else {

    print("Problem")
    return

}

self.view.addSubview(CC1)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: CC1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: CC0Parent, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

])

}
```

This throws the problem print

Comment: Your can always access a views parent via the **superview** property. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
// guard below ensures you have the parent AND grandparent views 
guard let cc1Parent = cc1.superview, let cc0Parent = cc1Parent.superview else {
    // problem with accessing parent views 
    return
}

// now just set your constraints as per below 
NSLayoutConstraint(item: cc1, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cc1Parent, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
```

EDIT: For UIView put code in awakeFromNib()

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
super.awakeFromNib()
// Set layout constraints here

}
```

Comment: Sorry for being unclear I would like to have the constraint activation happening in the CC0 UIView class if that is any help. I put your code in the program but it returns a problem while accessing the parent view. Ill but an update of my code maybe I did something wrong. And thanks for the help XD

Comment: Have you tried setting up the layout constraints in the ViewDidload method of CC0 UIView class? You should be able to correctly access CC0's parent and grand parent in its ViewDidLoad method

Comment: I currently have all of my code in the init of CC0, how do I put it in the ViewDidload, because it does not have an override function called viewDidload. So where is the ViewDidload of a "class SignUIView: UIView {}"

Comment: Oh I see.. Are you using xib to create the view for CC0? If so try put the code inside awakeFromNib()... I have edited my answer to show this.